# Magento 1.9 - how does the 'Add to Cart' functionality work for logged-in users and non-logged-in users

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Could I get a detailed step-by-step process about how Magento adds a product to the cart for both logged-in and non-logged-in customers? Preferably which controllers/models are involved and the database tables used (if any for non-logged-in customers).

I have having an issue where a non-logged-in customer cannot to add a product to an empty basket whereas a logged-in customer has no issues ([see here for more explanation on this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362576/magento-1-9-product-not-being-added-to-basket-for-logged-out-users)).

Any info could help me diagnose this. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: add to cart works for logged in users ?

Comment: Yes, I created a custom module that override then conventional dropdown approach for config products, when a non-logged-in user logs into their account they cannot add this product to the basket (unless it's not empty) however for users that are logged in, it works fine.